# Aliase a class function to be assigned from init method

Tags: python, alias

Given I have a class such as:

```
class Model(object):
    def __init__(self, foo = 'bar'):
        if foo == 'bar':
            self.f = self._sse
        else:
            self.f = None

    def _sse():
        pass
```

Is there a way I can create an alias so I do not have to check what's the value of the non-positional argument `foo`? Something like

```
class Model(object):
    alias = {'bar': _sse}
    def __init__(self, foo = 'bar'):
        self.f = foo

    def _sse():
        pass
```

Comment: `self.f = alias.get(foo)` but make sure the namespaces match, you might have to create the dict inside the `__init__`.

Comment: If you only have 1 alias, then using an `if` is a sensible solution and anything else would be over-engineered. If you have many aliases, see [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](//stackoverflow.com/q/60208)

Comment: It's more than 1 alias, this was just a minimal example.

Comment: @b-fg would you edit your question to give more context and actually explain the problem you're trying to solve with this "solution" ? Looks like a possible XY problem to me and there might be better ways.

Comment: I have used @KlausD. suggestion an included `alias` in the `__init__` method. Please see my suggested solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @KlausD. suggestion and including `alias` in the `__init__` method does the trick for me.

```
class Model(object):
    def __init__(self, foo = 'bar'):
        alias = {'bar': self._sse,
                 'bar2': self._sse2}

        self.f = alias.get(foo)

    def _sse(self):
        print('in sse')
    def _sse2(self):
        print('in sse2')


m = Model(foo='bar')
m.f() # in sse
m = Model(foo='bar2')
m.f() # in sse2
```

Answer (score 1):

Technical answer: you can do it by defining the target function *before* the initializer, referencing this function as the default argument (Python functions are objects too), and manually invoking the descriptor protocol on the target function:

```
>>> class Model(object):
...     def _sse(self):
...         print("in self._sse")
...     def __init__(self, foo=_sse):
...         self.f = foo.__get__(self, type(self))
... 
>>> m = Model()
>>> m.f()
in self._sse
```

Just note that with this solution, if you want to pass another function, this function has to take `self` as first argument :

```
>>> # doesn't work
... def bar(): print("bar")
... 
>>> m2 = Model(bar)
>>> m2.f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bar() takes no arguments (1 given)
>>> # works:
... def baaz(self): print("baaz({})".format(self))
... 
>>> m3 = Model(baaz)
>>> m3.f()
baaz(<__main__.Model object at 0x7fc3e2337090>)
```

Now from a readability POV this is barely an improvement IMHO...

EDIT: as Aran-Fey mentions, this doesn't exactly answer the question so for a more "literal" version (and that doesn't require special definitions ordering etc):

```
class Model(object):
    def _sse(self):
        print("in self._sse")

    alias = {"bar": "_sse"}

    def __init__(self, foo="bar"):
        self.f = getattr(self, self.alias.get(foo, "___"), None)
```

But this is still not improving readability...

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. You didn't implement an alias for the `_sse` method, which is what was asked.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I indeed answered based on what I thought the OP really wanted instead of what he explicitely asked - cf my edited answer for a more literal solution.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: In your first solution, what would happen if, in `__init__()`, `foo` were to be directly assigned to `self.f`? (As in `self.f = foo`)

Comment: @fountainhead then you couldn't call `self.f()` directly, you'd have to use `self.f(self)`. You can read this for more in-depth informations: https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod (caveat: it's not up to date wrt/ some python3 changes, but the core principle is still the same)

Comment: @fountainhead which Python version ?

Comment: Well, I tried this: I simplified your `__init__()` to do just `Model.f = foo`. I was able to invoke `self.f()` from another method of `Model`. I was also able to invoke `model_instance.f()` from outside the class. In both cases, the `self` got successfully injected (since I didn't get an error about missing `self`). Not sure what to make of this. Using Python 3.6.6

Comment: Ok. `Model.f` is not the same as `self.f`, and the result is indeed totally different, _as explained in the link I posted in a previous comment_.  Note that the differences between setting `Model.f` and `self.f` are not restricted to what `self.f` evals to, it also changes the definition of `f` for ALL instances of `Model` - which is certainly not what the OP wants.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: Thanks very much, for the patient replies. Clearly understand now why you didn't just set `Model.f` -- surely not what OP wants. Will take me some more time to relate/connect that reference link to what you're doing here. Thanks again.

Comment: I have used @KlausD. suggestion an included `alias` in the `__init__` method. Please see my suggested solution.

Comment: Also, thanks for this discussion, it was interesting too.